# Efficiently replace values in pandas column with matching pairs (millions of rows and thousands of pairs)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe of about 20 million rows, I want to replace 50 thousand of User Ids with their corresponding names.

I have a dictionnary `names` which contains matching Ids and names.

This is how I wanted to proceed

`databse['user_id'].replace(names, inplace=True)`

I did a first batch to test with only 1000 Ids to replace, this took me 20 minutes, this means that if I do it on the whole 50k Ids it would take about 17hours.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `map`  is significantly faster for these kind of stuff. Try `database['user_id'] = database['user_id'].map(names)` It is not like replace though, you cannot do it batch by batch because it will return NaN if it cannot find a value. You may overcome this with `database['user_id'] = database['user_id'].map(names).fillna(database['user_id'])`

Comment: yes indeed, it only took 5 seconds !